Prove that the set of points $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $f$ does not admit a local inverse is closed.
I'm currently studying multivariable-calculus, and I came across this problem in the Inverse Function Theorem section of the notes on the course.
Question
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuously differentiable function. Prove that the set of points $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $f$ does not admit a local inverse, is closed.
My attempt
Of course, with the knowledge of the Inverse Function theorem, we know that if $f$ is not invertible at a vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ , then $det(Df(x))=0$, so my first attempt was to characterize this set as the following set:
B = {$a \in \mathbb{R}^n | det(Df(a)=0$}
And then, using the conditions that $f$ is continuously differentiable and knowing the determinant is a continuous function on the entries of the matrix, proving this set is the preimage of {$0$} under a continuous function, and since {$0$} is obviously closed, then our set is too.
But after thinking of it, then I realized there are functions like $x^3$ with $x=0$ that have some $x$ such that $det(Df(x))=0$ but f is invertible locally there, wich implies the set I defined is not actually the same set, but a set that contains $A$. Obviously, the fact that this set is closed does not mean the set $A$ is closed.
I tried some other things to fix the argument, but I don't really know how to treat with the border or the closure of a set like this, and I really get messy things when I try this arguments.
I would like to know if there's a way to finish my argument, or if there is another way to prove this, since there is not only one way to prove things in topology. Any type of help would be appreciated :)
Edit
I'm not entirely sure about the meaning of "local inverse", but I guess, that given a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, to be locally invertible means you can find the open sets given by the Inverse Function theorem for it, as it states the following:
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuously differentiable function. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at a point $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and that the derivative $Df(a)$ (the Jacobian matrix of partial derivatives of $f$ at $a$) is invertible, i.e., $\det(Df(a)) \neq 0$.
Then, there exists an open neighborhood $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of $a$ and an open neighborhood $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of $f(a)$ such that $f$ restricted to $U$ is a bijection from $U$ onto $V$, and the inverse function $f^{-1}: V \to U$ is also continuously differentiable.
Moreover, for all $x \in U$, the derivative of the inverse function satisfies
$D(f^{-1})(f(x)) = [Df(x)]^{-1}$

The function $g(x):=\det Df(x)$ is continuous, therefore $g^{-1}({0})$ is closed, being the preimage of a closed set?

Yes, exactly, but this only proves the set {$a \in \mathbb{R}^n | det(Df(a)=0$} is closed, and as I pointed out, this set is not exactly the same as $A$ defined in the question. This is a closed set that contains $A$.

You should state what does "local inverse" mean in the context of your question.

Well, then the set of points $x$ where local inverse exists automatically satisfies $det(Df(x))\ne 0$. If this is a homework problem, I suggest you ask your instructor for a clarification.

It seems like it should be almost trivial to show directly from the definition that the set of points where $f$ does admit a local inverse is open.

@KendallRodriguez sorry, you are right, it's not necessarily the same as $A$. The answer below is correct, using the definition of open sets.
